# Data studio calculated fields

Tags: aggregate, looker-studio, calculated-field

I have the following dataset:

| Week # | Company Name | Product | # of transactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Week1 | Company A | Product 1 | 100 |
| Week1 | Company B | Product 1 | 30 |
| Week1 | Company A | Product 2 | 100 |
| Week2 | Company B | Product 2 | 50 |

My goal is:

1. for each COMPANY (there could be multiple rows per company) calculate **Usage score** with the following formula `total # of transactions per company/100`. For example, from the table above Company A has 200 transactions and Usage score=2 - I've done it successfully
2. categorize each company per the following formula: `when usage score>1 then "promoter" else "critic"` - I've done it successfully
3. Count promoters and critics - that's where I fail.  Data studio in this case calculates Usage score and NPS per **row**, not per company. Therefore, I have promoters per product, not per company.

please help, I'd appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by Re-aggregating the Datasource with itself where the Second Join is the Datasource itself with the Key `Company Name` and the Metric  `Usage score` make sure to set its Aggregation to Average.

Now you have a new Datasource with each Company and Row having its Usage Score in one column.

Unfortunately I don't understand the NPM part.
Hope this help though